# Why does the Variance of Laplace very different for OpenCV and scikit-image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

**TL;DR:** How can I use `skimage.filters.laplace(image).var()` in a way to get the same value as `cv2.Laplacian(image, CV_64F).var()` and `skimage.filters.sobel(image)` to get same value as `cv2.Sobel(image)` ?

I have the following code to find the [Laplace Variance for blur detection](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import requests
from PIL import Image
import urllib
from skimage.filters import laplace, sobel, roberts
from io import BytesIO
from skimage import color
from skimage import io as sk_io

def url_to_image(url): # Get image from url
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    return image

def simple_blur(gray:np.ndarray)->float:
    '''
    Use Laplacian Variance to find if an image has blur or not. It is very critical to find the threshold and is vert data specific
    args:
        gray: Grayscale Image
    '''
    return cv2.Laplacian(gray, CV_64F).var()
```

So when I try to find the Laplace variance from OpenCV and scikit-image, it gives me two different values:

```
laplace(color.rgb2gray(sk_io.imread(url))).var()
>> 1.1086769139613736e-05

simple_blur(url_to_image(url))
>> 0.6622495826224196
```

Which one should I use or how can I get same number from both the functions?

Also, How can I use the `cv2.Sobel(image)` given in `OpenCV` **EXACTLY** to get the results from `sobel(image) # given in scikit-image`?

[This is the Image Link](https://instasolv1.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/QuestionBank/5edc78c3ee44dd06fca0fa73/crop_image.png)

Comment: Some tools normalize and others do not. So normalize them as needed by dividing by the sum of absolute values of the elements. A simple blur is not the same as a laplacian filter.

Comment: "How can I use skimage.filters.laplace(image) in a way to get the same value as cv2.Laplacian(image, CV_64F).var()". You should not compare one laplacian to a laplacian with variance added.

Comment: I ran Pearson Correlation and got score of 1 for both. They fit on Regression Line perfectly. So it means I can use one and discard the other?

Comment: You should start by making sure that the difference is not produced by the image reading and/or conversion to RGB. Compare `img = url_to_image(url); res1 = cv2.Laplacian(img, CV_64F).var(); res2 = skimage.filters.laplace(img).var()`

Comment: I made sure of that exactly in the starting. These methods of  opening images are from the official websites only. Also, I am using the `Grayscale` image and both repos use the same formula so it shouldn't matter.